# How to interpret "un peu" in the expression "c'est un peu comme si ..."?

Tags: sens, adverbes

> C'est **un peu** comme si ...

I have always thought that "un peu" here clearly means "a little/bit (like)", but the fact that "un peu" in "un peu partout" is to be construed as "almost / pretty much (everywhere)" leads me to assume that "un peu comme si" too can have the meaning of "almost / a lot (like)" rather than "a little/bit (like)".

I also wonder if there is another expression where the meaning of "un peu" leans towards "almost / a lot", as in "un peu partout".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **un peu** add a nuance on an absolute word like *partout*.
So **un peu partout** means "not everwhere, but almost everywhere".

I translate **C'est un peu comme si** in "It's nearly like".
So the sentence seems to be less categoric.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I wouldn't translate ***un peu partout*** by "almost everywhere" which is *presque partout* but more by something like "**sparsely/randomly/scattered** all over the place".

Similarly, ***un peu comme si*** means ***somewhat like if*** instead of "a lot like if", i.e. is more about **quality** than **quantity**.